# How I can clean the pdf view

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I have a form that makes a pdf when finished and I'm using flutter_pdfview package to view the pdf. I expect to finish the form and view the pdf, but if I want to modify something I want to see the changes, but I just see the first version of the pdf. I have this theory that if I clean the String of the path that pdfview uses to render the pdf. Maybe I could see some changes, but well I have no idea.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You have to clean the Pipeline from where data is coming first you will show the text if you want to clean then u have to put an button for cleaning the pipeline from where data is coming eg:String,List Whatever .

Comment: How can I clean a String for example?

Comment: You have set a button when u press the pipeline clear or you can also use in initstate